# Помогите решить задачу с преобразованием величин

Tags: java, алгоритм, потоки-данных, поток-ввода

"*Дан перевод некоторых величин в формате a V = b W, где a, b – числа; V, W – названия величин (могут быть любые)*..." - алгоритм должен принимать некоторые образцовые данные, вычислять на их основе коэффициенты перевода и использовать их для ответа: "... *следом дана последовательность с неизвестным вторым числом в формате a V = ? W, необходимо найти величину, обозначенную в пропорции знаком вопроса*..."
Все казалось бы просто, если не одно но: не обязательно пара V:W будет повторяться, т.е. надо так же вычислить коэффициенты перевода для величин не имеющих примера. Например:
*1 byte = 8 bit

1024 byte = 1 kilobyte
 
1 kilobyte = ? bit*

Аналитически я легко могу применить соотношение (byte/bit)*(kilobyte/byte), если они уже встречались во входных данных, но для любых данных, в которых одна из величин ранее упоминалась в одной строке, но есть взаимосвязь со второй величиной, поступившей в другой строке на вход алгоритма (программы) не получается.
Подскажите как решить эту задачу в потоке данных. Пишу на java, но понимаю множество других языков.

Comment: возьмите обычную Map, записывайте в нее соотношения  и обращайтесь к ней для сопоставления типов. в чем вопрос то?

Comment: @ДмитрийАлександрович не всем может быть знакомо, что такое "обычное Map" и как к ней обращаться.

Comment: да, я использую Map<String, Double> где Key: String vw = V + ":" + W; а Value: Double k = a/b;  если b != "?" , но не могу отсюда вытащить V1:W2

Comment: Стройте граф, где вершины - единицы измерения, ребра - соотношения между ними. Потом просто находите путь между двумя нужными вершинами.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо за совет использовать граф и Map.
Поступил следующим образом: при вводе формул без вопросительного знака в "a V = b W" данные сохраняются в `Map<String,Double>`, где ключ - направленное ребро графа `V:W`, а значение соответствующий ему коэффициент b/a. Причем, сразу сохраняются, как прямой `V:W`, так и обратный `W:V`. Затем проходимся по мапе и ищем все совпадения по `V1 == V2`, но различные по `W1 != W2` и перемножаем их коэффициенты, сохраняем с ключем `W1:W2`. Таким образом, находятся все ребра полного графа.

Также введена проверка на наличие соответствующего ключа:

```
if(map.containsKey(s3)) map.replace(s3,map.get(s2),k3);<br> else map.put(s3, k3);
```

Answer (score 1):

Тогда так... Берете Map - это коллекция типа ключ - значение. На основе ее-любимой строите такую конструкцию

```
Map <String, Map<String, Integer>> map = new HashMap<>().
```

Теперь каждую новую пару парсите и раскладываете тким способом:
1. Ключ первой коллекции типа String - тип данных, приведенных в формуле к единице
2. Ключ второй коллекции, вложенной в первую (вся коллекция является значением , которое можно получить по ключу внешней коллекции) - типа String  - тип данных, противоположенный в формуле единице.
3. И наконец значение вложенной коллекции типа Integer либо возможно потребуется Double - является значением в формуле , которое приравнено к единице.

Таким образом, вы парсите формулу, смотрите, в какой ее части есть единица либо приводите к единице наименьшее значение, после чего по типу данных обращаетесь к коллекции, получая вложенную коллекцию, откуда опять же по нужному типу данных получаете множитель для расчета.

То выражение, которое я написал, называется multimap, т.е. коллекция , в которой ключу соответствует не одно, а множество значений - вторая вложенная коллекция. Для добавления в нее элементов проще всего использовать функционал Java8 : 
`map.computeIfAbsent(k1, (v1) -> new HashMap<String, Integer>).put(k2, v2);`

Но можно и строить граф, как вам подсказали...
Граф - решение более красивое, но всю логику работы придется реализовать вам ручками. Здесь все не так красиво, но по сути писать ничего не надо, все из коробки. Ну , не считая парсер, он вам нужен для любого решения...